# Eagle; Renumber Parts deletes everything in my schematic

Tags: eaglecad

I tried to use the renumber parts tool on my schematic (with default settings) and it deleted everything, leaving an empty schematic behind.  There are some user defined parts in my schematic, but mostly basic stuff like resistors and capacitors.  I can't find anything about this on the internet.
Here's my schematic
[image]

Comment: And your Q is ?

Comment: what is `empty schematic`?

Comment: You schematic is too small to read the part numbers, please post a larger one. Perhaps one of the parts is corrupt. Remove half the parts and try renumbering again. If still no good remove the other half instead, then half of that half etc. If nothing works draw a new schematic with a few parts on it. Can you renumber it?